# How to make numbered tables with numbers that take no space in Microsoft Office Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a few tables with symbols in Word and I want to number them, but numbering seems to take a huge amount of space from each box which makes the whole thing look horrible. I can't even see half the symbols anymore, they're off the page.

How do I make numbered tables with numbers that don't take that extra space ? As if the numbers weren't there.

Basically I don't want the numbers to interact with anything I write in the table, they should be in the background, somewhere in the corner of the boxes.

Here are two images to make things clearer:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clear about what you are trying to do. Can you please [edit] your question to provide more precise detail and possibly a screen shot of some sort? This will help you receive a more accurate answer to your question.

Comment: @CharlieRB seems clear to me, but he's added screenshots now

Answer (score 1):

The following isn't a great solution as it'd take some time to do but you can draw text boxes. These you can position anywhere and they don't interfere. Use ctrl+arrow keys, to move it about finely.

this for example is done with a textbox over text written into a document. This is a screenshot taken from   MS word.
[image]

To do that you'd want the drawing toolbar, you'd click textbox. And set it to no fill and no line.

Comment: also if drawing something in ms word, I the following isn't a necessity , technically, but just a suggestion- turning the "canvas" off, it's an annoying feature they added in some word version. tools..options turn off "automatically..drawing canvas".